# File upload through okhttp3

Tags: java, android, file-upload, okhttp

After selecting image,doc or pdf,I want to pass them through okhttp3.How do i go about doing this?

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==0){
        Log.d("uri data",""+data.getData());

        selectedFileUri = data.getData();
        fileToBeUploaded = new File(""+selectedFileUri);
        fileName = fileToBeUploaded.getName();
        Log.d("filename",""+fileName);
```

And in okhttp 3

```
RequestBody formBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("data[User][user_picture]", fileToBeUploaded.getName(),RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), fileToBeUploaded))
```

The error showing is

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: content:/com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A40227: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Thanks.

Comment: `Log.d("filename",""+fileName);`. Welll what does it log/print? Does it make sense?

Comment: `FileNotFoundException: content:/com.andr.....` The uploader expects a file path. But this it is a non valid file path. No wonder that 'the file' is not found. This is a content scheme. It cannot handle conten schemes in this way.

Comment: @greenapps Then what should i do to get the file path and hence the file?

Comment: First find out if the multipart library has a member that accepts a content scheme. If you really need a file path then google for getrealpathfromuri.  But that method often fails.

Comment: @greenapps Ok i think i will create a temporary file, from a bitmap, from the content uri and after sending this file I will delete it.Is this a good way to go?

Comment: Bitmap? For a doc or pdf? Not even for an image file a good approch. But a temporary file is ok. Just copy the contents to a file. Open an InputStream and a FileOutputStream. In a loop read chunks from the input stream and write them to the file output stream.

Comment: @greenapps I have implemented this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I am answering this question myself.

So I am firstly opening an outputstream to a temporary file.

```
imageTempUploadfile=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/inpaint/");
if(!imageTempUploadfile.exists())
    imageTempUploadfile.mkdirs();
    imageTempUploadfile2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/inpaint/"+"file"+".docx");
OutputStream outputTempFileStream = new FileOutputStream(imageTempUploadfile2);
```

The extension depends upon the mime type.You can find the mime type by

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==0){
        Log.d("uri data",""+data.getData());

        String mimetype = context.getContentResolver().getType(data.getData());

        selectedFileUri = data.getData();
```

Now to read from the file and write its contents in the temporary file

```
selectedFileInputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedFileUri);
```

Now to write into the file

```
try {
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024]; // or other buffer size
        int read;

        while ((read = selectedFileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputTempFileStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        outputTempFileStream.flush();
    } finally {
        outputTempFileStream.close();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // handle exception, define IOException and others
}
```

And finally

```
MultipartUtility multipart = new MultipartUtility(urlLeaveFormApply, charset);
multipart.addFilePart("data[User][user_picture]", imageTempUploadfile2);
```

At the end after success

```
imageTempUploadfile2.delete();
```