# Cant upload file through okhttp3

Tags: java, android, file-upload, okhttp

I get the file on activity result.Or should i say the content uri version of it.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==0){
        Log.d("uri data",""+data.getData());
        selectedFileUri = data.getData();
```

My question is how do i send this file through okhttp3 method?

The okhttp 3 method is as follows

```
multipart.addFilePart("data[User][user_picture]", selectedFileUri);
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
    .addFormDataPart("image", "your file name.png",
        RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, new File("your absolute file path")))
    .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("Your url")
    .post(requestBody)
    .build();

//Check the response
try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
  if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

  System.out.println(response.body().string());
}
```

Go through this blog for `URI` [How to Consume Content From a Uri](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html)

**OR**

[Get filename and path from URI from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore/3414749#3414749)

Comment: Ok i will try this and notify you

Comment: Upvoting your answer as it helped me.I have answered this question on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140447/file-upload-through-okhttp3